# How to get datatypes from XSD generic

Tags: java, xml, types, xsd, xerces

I want to get the datatypes of an XSD. It have to be static, cause the XSD could be variate. 
In my case I know the element names.

Small sample of XSD, but it could be go deeper:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Order">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="OrderNo"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="OrderDate"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="NameNo"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I tried with `org.apache.xerces.xs` but don´t know how to get the Object `XSParticleDecl` with Interface `XSElementDeclaration` from root Elem

I expect the output for each individual element name to be the type.

Comment: An XSD is just XML. Take a look at some tutorials on how to process XML. A simple solution would be to make a Pojo that models the XML, then deserialize into it.

Comment: @user489041 i know the Definiton of XSD, but it´s not the same to search for. And a Pojo is not the solution, because of generics.

Comment: @Faer Were you able to do it using the `Xerces`? I need to implement something like this in my application. I need to obtain the datatype of the objects in XML from the XSD. If you have the small code snippet can you please post it here?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally best to work with a schema processor that gives you some kind of access to the "schema component model" rather than working directly with source XSD documents.

The Xerces schema API is one approach but I don't have experience with that and can't help you with it.

Saxon offers two alternatives:

(a) you can generate an SCM file representing the compiled schema. This is an XML file, so it can be processed easily using XSLT or XQuery.

(b) there's a set of extension functions, starting with saxon:schema() that allow you to explore the schema directly from XPath.

I would personally work with an SCM file. The SCM file for your schema is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scm:schema xmlns:scm="http://ns.saxonica.com/schema-component-model"
            generatedAt="2019-08-22T18:14:23.59+01:00"
            xsdVersion="1.1">
   <scm:element id="C0"
                name="Order"
                type="C1"
                global="true"
                nillable="false"
                abstract="false"/>
   <scm:complexType id="C1"
                    base="#anyType"
                    derivationMethod="restriction"
                    abstract="false"
                    variety="element-only">
      <scm:modelGroupParticle minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
         <scm:sequence>
            <scm:elementParticle minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="C2"/>
            <scm:elementParticle minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="C3"/>
            <scm:elementParticle minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="C4"/>
            <scm:elementParticle minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="C5"/>
         </scm:sequence>
      </scm:modelGroupParticle>
      <scm:finiteStateMachine initialState="0">
         <scm:state nr="0">
            <scm:edge term="C2" to="1"/>
         </scm:state>
         <scm:state nr="1">
            <scm:edge term="C3" to="2"/>
         </scm:state>
         <scm:state nr="2">
            <scm:edge term="C4" to="3"/>
         </scm:state>
         <scm:state nr="3">
            <scm:edge term="C5" to="4"/>
         </scm:state>
         <scm:state nr="4" final="true"/>
      </scm:finiteStateMachine>
   </scm:complexType>
   <scm:element id="C2"
                name="OrderNo"
                type="#float"
                global="false"
                containingComplexType="C1"
                nillable="false"
                abstract="false"/>
   <scm:element id="C3"
                name="OrderDate"
                type="#string"
                global="false"
                containingComplexType="C1"
                nillable="false"
                abstract="false"/>
   <scm:element id="C4"
                name="Name"
                type="#string"
                global="false"
                containingComplexType="C1"
                nillable="false"
                abstract="false"/>
   <scm:element id="C5"
                name="NameNo"
                type="#float"
                global="false"
                containingComplexType="C1"
                nillable="false"
                abstract="false"/>
</scm:schema>
<?Σ 954c7f5b?>
```

Built-in types are represented using, for example, type="#float", whereas user-defined types will be represented by a reference such as `type="C89"` where C89 is a reference to the `@id` attribute of an `scm:simpleType` or `scm:complexType` child of the `scm:schema` element.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Learned something new but I don´t want to add an extra step for converting. I´m interested how it is going like with the XSD :)